# Convergence in distribution of empirical cdf almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

> Given i.i.d. random variables $\{X_n\}$, define the empirical cdf
> $$ \hat{F}_n(\omega, x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbf{1}_{X_i(\omega) \leq x}$$
> where $\omega \in \Omega$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\hat{F}_n(\cdot, \cdot) \overset{d}{\to} F$ as $n \to \infty$, i.e.
> $$ P\left(\left\{\omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{F}_n(\omega, x) = F(x)\text{ for every } x \in C(F)\right\}\right)=1$$

I know that each $\hat{F}_n(\cdot, x)$ is a random variable, and each $\hat{F}_n(\omega, \cdot)$ is a cdf. Furthermore, for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\hat{F}_n(\cdot, x) \overset{as}{\to} F$ by the Strong Law of Large Numbers; thus, each
$$ P\left(\left\{\omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{F}_n(\omega, x) = F(x)\right\}\right) := P(A_x) = 1. $$

The problem is extending this to *almost all* $x$. If I only had to deal with countably many $x$, then I could just take a countable union of $A_x^c$ and obtain the result. It has been hinted that the problem can be reduced to this case, but I am still unable to figure out how.

Comment: can't you just approximate each $x$ by a countable sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a concise proof of Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem, it gives the uniform
convergence, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_t|F_n(t)-F(t)|=0)=1. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
which also includes what you want.

By the strong law of Large numbers, as $n\to\infty$
\begin{gather*}
 F_n(t)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{\{X_i\le t\}} \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\mathsf{E}[I_{\{X_1\le t\}}]=F(t), \quad 
   \forall t\in\mathbb{R}, \tag{2}\\
 F_n(t-)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{\{X_i< t\}} \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\mathsf{E}[I_{\{X_1< t\}}]=F(t-), \quad 
   \forall t\in\mathbb{R}. \tag{3}  
\end{gather*}

Given a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, take
$$  t_0=-\infty, \quad t_i= \sup\{t: F(t)-F(t_{i-1})\le \varepsilon \}, \quad i\ge 1,
$$
then there exist finite $k\le 1/\epsilon+1 $ and $-\infty=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_k=\infty$ satisfy
$$ F(t_i-)-F(t_{i-1})\le \epsilon,\qquad 1\le i \le k.$$
Now, for
$t_{i-1}\le t<t_i$,
\begin{gather*}
 F_n(t_{i-1})\le F_n(t)\le F_n(t_i-),\qquad F(t_{i-1})\le F(t)\le F(t_i-)\\
 F_n(t)-F(t)\le F_n(t_i-) -F(t_i-)+\varepsilon,\\
 F(t)-F_n(t)\le F(t_{i-1})- F_n(t_{i-1}) + \varepsilon.
\end{gather*}
Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
 &\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(t)-F(t)| \\
 &\quad\le \sup_{1\le i\le k} [|F_n(t_{i-1})-F(t_{i-1})|+F_n(t_i-)-F(t_i-)] + \varepsilon
\end{align*}
Now from (2),(3) easy to get
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}\Big(\varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(t)-F(t)|\le \varepsilon\Big)=1.
\end{equation*}
Hence,  (1) is also true.

Comment: This looks good, thanks (+1)!

Comment: In order to construct such a partition you take $k \in \mathbb N$ in such a way that $\frac {1} {k + 1} \lt \varepsilon.$ Since $t_i$'s are jump points of jump $\geq \varepsilon$ and $F$ is incraesing it follows that $F(t_i) \geq i \varepsilon$ for any $i \geq 1.$ So if $F(t_i-) - F(t_{i-1}) \geq \varepsilon$ for some $1 \leq i \leq k,$ then $F(t_i) \geq (i + 1) \varepsilon$ and since $F$ has jump more than $\varepsilon$ at each $t_j,$ it then follows that $F(t_k) \geq (k + 1) \varepsilon \gt 1,$ a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @Anacardium Thank you for your commments. I add the details of how to get $\{t_i\}$. If you have any questions about it ,please tell me, I like discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

While the existing answer provides a valid route to proving the desired result via the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, I would like to offer a more simpler approach that avoids some of the technicalities involved in the theorem's proof.

You have already shown (using Kolmogorov's SLLN) that given $x \in \mathbb R,$ there exists $A_x \subseteq \Omega$ with $\mathbb P \left (A_x \right ) = 1,$ such that for all $\omega \in A_x,$ $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x) = F(x).$ Let $A = \bigcap\limits_{x \in \mathbb Q} A_x.$ Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, it follows that $\mathbb P (A) = 1.$ So $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x) = F(x),$ for all $\omega \in A$ and for all $x \in \mathbb Q.$ Now let $x_0 \in C(F)$ and choose $s,t \in \mathbb Q,$ such that $s \lt x_0 \lt t.$ Since $x \mapsto \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x)$ is a cdf for each $\omega \in \Omega,$ it follows that $\widehat {F_n} (\omega, s) \leq \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x_0) \leq \widehat {F_n} (\omega, t),$ for all $\omega \in A.$ Thus for all $\omega \in A$ we have $$F(s) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, s) \leq \liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x_0) \leq \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x_0) \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, t) = F(t).$$ This is true for any $s, t \in \mathbb Q$ with $s \lt x \lt t.$ Since $x_0 \in C(F),$ letting $s \to x_0^-$ and $t \to x_0^+,$ we have $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x_0) = F(x_0)$$ for all $\omega \in A.$ This shows that $$A \subseteq \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ :\ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \widehat {F_n} (\omega, x) = 0\ \text {for all}\ x \in C(F) \right \}.$$ Since $\mathbb P (A) = 1,$ the required result follows. $\square$